# Passing resource limit in new-app command

Tags: openshift

Is there a way to pass resource limits in the new-app command to create, build and deploy an application on openshift? Currently I have to modify resource limits in build config and deployment config every time I create an application using new-app command.

Comment: Instead of using `oc new-app`, it's better to put the build config and deployment config in scm and apply the configuration through a template.